# when use * about numpy.array and numpy.matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(3, 1)
b = np.array([4, 5]).reshape(2,1)
```

When I use `a*b.T`, I am thinking a wrong output because there is a difference in their shapes (using `*` performs element-wise multiplication for an array).
But the result returns Matrix multiplication, like this:

```
[[ 4, 5],
 [ 8, 10],
 [12, 15]]

# this shape is (3, 2)
```

Why does it work like this?

Comment: If you have reshaped a to (3,1) and b to (2,1). Then a*b.T should result in (3,2). 
`a*b.T ~= (3,1)*(1,2)`. Inner dimensions match. So the resultant matrix will be the outer dimensions 3 and 2. Therefore (3,2)

Comment: I know you mean ,but when used *  means element-wise multiplication about array ,a&b they type is array. For example if you have c(array type) shape is (2, 3) * d(array type) shape is (3, 2) is be wrong , because they shape is difference.@nikpod

Answer (score 1):

Your `a * b.T` is element multiplication, and works because of `broadcasting`.  Addition, and many other binary operations work with this pair of shapes.

`a` is (3,1).  `b.T` is (1,2).  Broadcasting combines (3,1) with (1,2) to produce (3,2).  The size 1 dimension is adjusted to match the other non-zero dimension.

Unless you make arrays with `np.matrix`, `*` does not perform mathematical `matrix multiplication`.  `np.dot` is used to perform that (`@` and `np.einsum` also do this).

With this particular combination of shapes, the `dot` product is the same.  `np.outer(a,b)` also produces this, the mathematical `outer product`.  `np.dot` matches the last dimension of `a` with the 2nd to the last dimension of `b.T`.  In this case they are both 1.  `dot` is more interesting when the shared dimension has multiple items, producing the familiar `sum of products`.

```
In [5]: np.dot(a, b.T)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 4,  5],
       [ 8, 10],
       [12, 15]])
```

'outer' addition:

```
In [3]: a + b.T
Out[3]: 
array([[5, 6],
       [6, 7],
       [7, 8]])
```

It may help to look at `a` and `b` like this:

```
In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [8]: b
Out[8]: 
array([[4],
       [5]])
In [9]: b.T
Out[9]: array([[4, 5]])
```

I generally don't use `matrix` to talk about `numpy` arrays unless they are created with `np.matrix`, or more frequently `scipy.sparse`.  `numpy` arrays can be 0d, 1d, 2d and higher.  I pay more attention to the shape than the names.

Comment: Yup, exactly what I just figured out from docs. Broadcasting is the reason OP gets that output.